# If $f$ is bounded below by some $m>0$ and $f \in \mathrm{BV}[a, b]$, how do I show that $\mathrm{TV}(1/f) \le \frac{1}{m} \mathrm{TV}(f)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Assuming $f$ is of bounded on $[a, b]$, I can show that $1/f$ is also of bounded variation as follows:

Given any partition $P$  of $[a, b]$ the variation of $1/f$ w.r.t. $P$ is
\begin{align*}
 \mathrm{V}(1/f; P)&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left|\frac{1}{f(x_{i})}-\frac{1}{f(x_{i-1})}\right|\\
 &=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{|f(x_{i-1})-f(x_{i})|}{|f(x_{i})f(x_{i-1})|}\\
 &\le \frac{1}{m^{2}} \sum_{k=1}^{n} |f(x_{i})-f(x_{i-1})| < \infty,
\end{align*}
so $1/f$ is indeed of bounded variation on $[a, b]$, but then this implies that the total variation:
\begin{align*}
 \mathrm{TV}(1/f) &= \sup_{P}\{V(1/f; P)\}\\
 &\le \frac{1}{m^{2}}\sup_{P} \{V(f;P)\}\\
 &= \frac{1}{m^{2}}\mathrm{TV}(f),
\end{align*}
and I'm not sure how to get $1/m$ instead of the $1/m^{2}$ that I end up with.

Comment: If you take $f(x) = x$, $0<a<b$ we have $\operatorname{var}_{[a,b]} f = b-a$ and $\operatorname{var}_{[a,b]} {1 \over f} = {1\over a} - {1 \over b} = {1 \over ab} \operatorname{var}_{[a,b]} f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get $m$ on RHS. Counter-example: $f(x)=\frac 1 3 x$ on $[1,2]$.  Here $m=\frac 1 3$ and $TV(f)=\frac 1 3$ so the right hand side is $1$. But $TV(\frac 1 f) \geq |\frac 1 {f(2)}-\frac 1 {f(1)}|=|\frac 3 2-3|=\frac 3 2 >1$.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out where I went wrong in my analysis. Can you help me, please?

Comment: @JohnSmith You did not go wrong. You can only get $\frac 1 {m^{2}}TV(f)$ on the right side. You cannot get $\frac 1 {m}TV(f)$. You have been given a wrong question.

Comment: Thank you so much!